# Как исключить один графиков в distplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Есть датасет с 7 столбцами, он выделен из большого датасета.
вида -

```
df_numeric = df[['1','2','3','4','5','6','type']]
```

type имеет значения 0 и 1

надо построить графики distplot в цикле.

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
num_cols=3
num_rows=len(df_num.columns.values)//num_cols + 1
for i, col in enumerate(df_numeric.columns.values):
    sns.distplot(df_numeric.query('type==1')[col], label ='try1',ax=plt.subplot(num_rows,
                                                                          num_cols, i+1))
    sns.distplot(df_numeric.query('type==0')[col], label ='try2')
    plt.title(col)
    if i ==0: plt.legend()
```

Как исключить из этих график, который отрисовывает по столбцу - type.
т.е. сделать только 6 графиков по столбцам 1-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df_numeric.columns.values):
    if col == 'type':
        continue
    ...
```